# Setting up Office 365 / Exchange 365 email in Mail (32-bit) without logging in as the user?

Tags: email, windows-7, microsoft-office-365

There's been a recent change in policy at the place where I work that I cannot login to a user account without the user being virtually or physically present.

In order to setup their account at present I login as their user, go to control panel, Mail (32-bit) and add their Exchange 365 / Office 365 account.   Then despite clicking the `remember my password` checkbox, on the Mail (32-bit) program, I have to type it in again for Outlook when the user logs in, and possibly enter the new domain name for their user.

Is there anyway I can set this up without logging into their account?  Or do I just have to wait for the user to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If autodiscover works correctly then I find just not creating any accounts and letting the wizard take care of it works 95% in my environment.  The wizard is more user friendly than 07/10 and should prompt for name, primary email address and password, then autoconfig and launch ok.

This is with Office 365 / Outlook 2013 32 bit, both c2r and msi on RDP server.

Ideally you wouldn't have to log into each new profile using the user's password.